# Pass Variable value in substring function using awk

Tags: linux, awk, substr

I am using awk `substr` function to get count of the occurence.

Eg :

```
cat amexe1_e1_dev_Vaibhav_SLM_6_slmlog.txt | /opt/apigee4/contrib/jq '.destinations[0].message.value' | sed -e 's|"\\||g' |tr -d ' '| sed -e 's|n"||g' | sed -e 's|[\]||g' | awk '{ print substr( $v, 1258 ) }' | grep -o ':'| wc -l
```

when I execute the below command I get the count as expected i.e 1 which is the actual result.

Now instead of passing 1258 directly , I wrap it inside the variable and then use it like below

```
POS=1258;
cat amexe1_e1_dev_Vaibhav_SLM_6_slmlog.txt | /opt/apigee4/contrib/jq '.destinations[0].message.value' | sed -e 's|"\\||g' |tr -d ' '| sed -e 's|n"||g' | sed -e 's|[\]||g' | awk '{ print substr( $v, $POS ) }' | grep -o ':'| wc -l
```

And when used in the command I get the result as 28, which is not expected as expected count is 1.

So what I was able to conclude is POS variable is not getting populated correctly, which should replace its value by 1258.

So the question is: How do I invoke the POS variable inside the command?

Comment: please provide a [mcve]. Also, have you checked [How to use shell variables in awk script](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19075671/1983854)?

Comment: please to read [how-to-use-shell-variables-in-awk-script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-to-use-shell-variables-in-awk-script)

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response .
awk -v var="$variable" 'BEGIN {print var}'
above method helped me to resolve the issue .

Comment: @Jose: Sure i will have a walk through over it .
Thank You Once again .